# Detect Chrome extension first run / update

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How can an extension find out that it is being run for the first time or has just been updated, so that the extension can perform some specific actions? (e.g. open a help page or update settings)

Comment: why you didn't chose this one? http://stackoverflow.com/a/14957674/4548520 it's right anwser - official event for first extension install

Answer (score 205):

In newer versions of Chrome (since Chrome 22), you can use the [`chrome.runtime.onInstalled`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#event-onInstalled) event, which is much cleaner.

Example:

```js
// Check whether new version is installed
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function(details){
    if(details.reason == "install"){
        console.log("This is a first install!");
    }else if(details.reason == "update"){
        var thisVersion = chrome.runtime.getManifest().version;
        console.log("Updated from " + details.previousVersion + " to " + thisVersion + "!");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this!  All I've found around the Internet is to store the extension's version in localStorage until I eventually stumbled across this answer, which was of course a workable solution, but I was so surprised that chrome didn't have something built-in for this!  I'm so glad that I have not been let down :)

Comment: Since Chrome 22, released in Sep 2012

Comment: chrome.runtime.onInstalled detects when the app or extension is installed in the background. What it does not do, however, is detect a first firing of the chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched event...

Comment: I used this code for a while and it worked great, until my extension requested a new permission on an update (which suspends the extension until the user accepts the permission). When the permission was accepted and the extension was unsuspended, the onInstalled event never fired and thus the update script never ran. Worth mentioning for those who run update scripts onInstalled, you might need to listen for a different event in situations where you have requested a new permission.

Comment: @Elimm seems like Chrome's bug, you should report on the bug tracker.

Comment: There are also spurious update events, but you can detect them with a couple of lines of additional code: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=303481

Comment: How can I get this to work on an unpacked chrome extension? I added the above code to my background.js but no luck

Comment: note that you don't see this console msgs .. use alerts for debugging

Comment: console.log works, certainly at least for the last few years but you have to open the background page for your extension using the chrome://extensions entry for your extension.

Comment: Actually, good old `localStorage` is a better option than `onInstalled`. Because `onInstalled` fires after the top level bg code is finished running and with this event there is no easy way to run code only when the extension was started without being installed.

Answer (score 87):

Updated answer to reflect v3 of manifest:

Chromium now has a [chrome.runtime](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime) set of APIs, which allow you to fetch the version of the extension.

To get the current version:

```
chrome.runtime.getManifest().version
```

To listen when the extension has been first installed, when the extension is updated to a new version, and when Chromium is updated to a new version, you can use the `onInstalled` event.

```js
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener((details) => {
   const currentVersion = chrome.runtime.getManifest().version
   const previousVersion = details.previousVersion
   const reason = details.reason
   
   console.log(`Previous Version: ${previousVersion }`)
   console.log(`Current Version: ${currentVersion }`)

   switch (reason) {
      case 'install':
         console.log('New User installed the extension.')
         break;
      case 'update':
         console.log('User has updated their extension.')
         break;
      case 'chrome_update':
      case 'shared_module_update':
      default:
         console.log('Other install events within the browser')
         break;
   }

})
```

Thats all!

---

Old answer, prior to 2011

If you want to check if the extension has been installed or updated, you can do something like this:

```js
function onInstall() {
    console.log("Extension Installed");
  }

  function onUpdate() {
    console.log("Extension Updated");
  }

  function getVersion() {
    var details = chrome.app.getDetails();
    return details.version;
  }

  // Check if the version has changed.
  var currVersion = getVersion();
  var prevVersion = localStorage['version']
  if (currVersion != prevVersion) {
    // Check if we just installed this extension.
    if (typeof prevVersion == 'undefined') {
      onInstall();
    } else {
      onUpdate();
    }
    localStorage['version'] = currVersion;
  }
```

Comment: If I run getVersion() in a content script in Gmail, I get the Gmail app version's number. I should point out there are a number of problems that will prevent this type of script from working: a) when you install a plugin, which needs to inject a content script into a page, and the page is already loaded, the content script does not get injected into the page, the page has to be reloaded). b) getting the version number of the plugin can be done from the background script, however the background script can't access the localStorage, only the content script can, which is not yet loaded...

Comment: this post is great... you should mark this one as an answer. Thanks Mohamed!

Comment: @VictorS the above is intended to be used within the background page, if your planning to use this in a content script, then just call chrome.app.getDetails().version directly. The reason why I did getVersion before is because in the early days of Chrome Extension development, there was no chrome.app object, so we had to XHR the manifest. You could do all this in a closure so you can guarantee your calling the right method. I usually encapsulate everything in a class object.

Comment: Great, this worked for me. Note that the above code is missing a semicolon, and "undefined" shouldn't have quotes.

Comment: @mpoisot Sorry to say, you are wrong about "undefined".  (I know I'm very late to this party but this may be important for others who stumble across here such as myself.)  He is *not* trying to check `prevVersion == 'undefined'`... he is checking `typeof prevVersion == 'undefined'`.  It is much more robust to use `typeof` when checking if a variable is undefined... see here to learn why: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3550319/130691

Comment: @JMTyler you're right about `undefined`. It's been too long so I can't remember why I put that.

Comment: @MohamedMansour, **This requires storage permission though.**

Comment: @Pacerier i though the storage permission just relates to `chrome.storage` not `localStorage`?

Comment: Thanks @MohamedMansour 

Answer (score 21):

Fortunately, there are now [events](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onInstalled) for this (since Chrome version 22, and 25 for update events).

For an installed event:

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {...});
```

For an OnUpdateAvailable event:

```
chrome.runtime.onUpdateAvailable.addListener(function() {...});
```

An important excerpt about OnUpdateAvailable from the developer docs says:

> Fired when an update is available, but isn't installed immediately because the app is currently running. If you do nothing, the update will be installed the next time the background page gets unloaded, if you want it to be installed sooner you can explicitly call chrome.runtime.reload().

Answer (score 9):

Simple. When the extension first runs, the `localStorage` is empty. On first run, you can write a flag there to mark all consequent runs as non-first.

Example, in background.htm:

```
var first_run = false;
if (!localStorage['ran_before']) {
  first_run = true;
  localStorage['ran_before'] = '1';
}

if (first_run) alert('This is the first run!');
```

**EDIT:** To check whether the extension has just been updated, store the version instead of a simple flag on first run, then when the current extension version (get it by `XmlHttpRequest`ing the manifest) doesn't equal the one stored in `localStorage`, the extension has been updated.

Comment: Careful not to do that in a content script. localStorage is shared with other code and extensions on the page.  So this wouldn't work in a content script.

Comment: For packaged apps, this is indeed a definite solution for use in background pages as a packaged app's `localStorage` is indeed in its own separate window and not shared with other code and extensions on the page as @huyz mentioned. For extensions, however, this is not the case.

Comment: **This requires storage permission though.**