# How to open a url while uninstalling Google Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome

I was able to do it in Firefox using nsIObserverService. Is there anything similar? Any link to proper documentation will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no hooks for uninstall within the Chrome extension API. Feel free to star the following feature if you want to see it included:

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=19383

Comment: No, but this is easy to work around.  See [FAQ Entry](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/faq.html#faq-firstrun)

Comment: Use first run! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399389/chrome-extension-first-run

Comment: Good news. Looks like it's available now. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-setUninstallURL

Answer (score 10):

You can now set an uninstall url as of Version 41 of chrome.

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=84556

Here is the documentation.
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-setUninstallURL

hths, future people who read this question.

Put it in background or service worker JavaScript file `chrome.runtime.setUninstallURL('your URL here');`

Comment: I suggest adding a unique identifier to the url and calling your backend to record the uninstall, followed by a redirect to some uninstall landing page or survey

Answer (score 1):

YThere is a new api may be do this thing after the version 20.

> chrome.runtime.setUninstallUrl

More datail: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#method-setUninstallUrl

also has the install hook:

> chrome.runtime.onInstalled

More detail: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#event-onInstalled

For the browser below 20, you have to declare the permission in manifest of "management". And then bind open new tab method to the onUninstalled

More detail: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management.html#event-onUninstalled

Comment: -1: `setUninstallUrl` hasn't made it to stable Chrome yet and the `onUninstalled` event of the management API is not called for the current extension.