# How do I let my chrome extension users know when the extension is updated?

Tags: google-chrome, popup, google-chrome-extension, auto-update

I want to show them a popup with the new features.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chrome extension update notification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11555051/chrome-extension-update-notification) (answers below are out of date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have submitted an answer and a working code example here **chrome extension first run**:
[Detect Chrome extension first run / update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399389/chrome-extension-first-run/2401788#2401788)

You get the `version` from the `manifest.json`, you store that into your `localStorage`. In your background page, you check if your `version` has been set (via undefined) if it isn't set you know that your extension just installed, otherwise if the versions changed, you know it is being updating

Answer (score 1):

Store `version` variable in a `localStorage` and have local `current_version` variable  hardcoded into javascript. Then during extension startup (in background.html) compare those two. After that update localStorage variable with the current version.

Comment: But now when a user first installs the extension, the version update popup will show too. How do you suggest I cope with that?

Comment: @Orny: Check if `version` exists?

Comment: but my current version doesn't have this system implemented.