# chrome.management.onEnabled Not Firing

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have this in my background.html:

```
chrome.management.onEnabled.addListener(function(ExtensionInfo info) {
  alert('123');
});
```

which gives me an error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

If I remove `info` from `function(ExtensionInfo info)`, I don't get any errors, but it's not firing the alert. Where did I go wrong?

Also, I added `"management"` inside `permissions` in manifest.json, so that's not the problem.

Comment: When are you expecting it to fire?

Comment: When the extension is enabled.

Comment: Your extension? Or other extensions?

Comment: I want to make a small check when my extension is enabled and close some tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to catch `chrome.management.onEnabled` event for your own extension.

If you are trying to execute some code on first extension installation then you would need to store some flag in a local storage.

**background.html**

```
if(!localStorage["first_run"]) {

    //do something at first run here

    localStorage["first_run"] = "done";

}
```

(for more advanced solution see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399389/chrome-extension-first-run/2401788#2401788))

If you want to execute some code each time extension starts (browser startup) just put in into `background.html`.