# Open a "Help" page after Chrome extension is installed first time

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am new to Chrome extension. I have a question about how to make the extension to open a "Help" page automatically after installation. Currently, I am able to check whether the extension is running the first time or not by saving a value into localStorage. But this checking is only carried out when using click the icon on the tool bar. Just wondering if there is a way that likes FF extension which uses the javascript in  to open a help page after the installation. Thanks.

Edit:
Thanks for the answer from davgothic. I have solved this problem.
I have another question about the popup. My extension checks the url of current tab,

```
if OK(url){
    //open a tab and do something
}
else{
    //display popup
}
```

Is it possible to show the popup in this way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect Chrome extension first run / update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399389/detect-chrome-extension-first-run-update)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> **UPDATE:** This method is no longer recommended. Please see [Nuhil's more recent answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24429523/268669).

I believe what you need to do is put something like this into a script in the `<head>` section of your extension's background page, e.g. `background.html`

```
function install_notice() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('install_time'))
        return;

    var now = new Date().getTime();
    localStorage.setItem('install_time', now);
    chrome.tabs.create({url: "installed.html"});
}
install_notice();
```

Comment: Thanks, I moved my isFirstRun() script from my options.html to background.html and it works. I also have another question, FDF extension has "gBrowser.getNotificationBox()" to display a notification box. Has chrome the same thing. I had a look the Desk notification already, but i think it is too much (permission ...) for a simple displaying server message/warning. I am looking at the popup at the moment, i do not know if it is easy to use in my case, because i need the popup to display just under the address bar of the browser. Any better ideas ?

Answer (score 95):

Check this updated and most reliable solution provided by Chrome: [chrome.runtime Event](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onInstalled)

```js
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function (object) {
    let externalUrl = "http://yoursite.com/";
    let internalUrl = chrome.runtime.getURL("views/onboarding.html");

    if (object.reason === chrome.runtime.OnInstalledReason.INSTALL) {
        chrome.tabs.create({ url: externalUrl }, function (tab) {
            console.log("New tab launched with http://yoursite.com/");
        });
    }
});
```

Add this to your `background.js` I mean the the page you defined on manifest like following,

```
....
"background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"],
      "persistent": false
  }
...
```

Comment: Don't forget to check `if(object.reason === 'install')` in the callback or else this will fire for updates too.

Comment: or even `if (chrome.runtime.OnInstalledReason.INSTALL === object.reason)`

Comment: Good solution. To open a local file you should add the 'tab part' it like this: `chrome.tabs.create({url:chrome.extension.getURL("help.html")}, function (tab) {
   console.log("New tab launched with local file");
  });`

Comment: simple one-liner:

`chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(({reason}) => {
  if (reason === 'install') chrome.tabs.create({ url: 'onboarding.html'});
});`

Comment: How to test this locally?

Comment: @abyesilyurt install it locally.

Answer (score 13):

As of now (Aug 2022) the right way to execute code on first install or update of an extension using Manifest V3 is by using the runtime.onInstalled event.

This event is documented here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onInstalled

There is one example for this exact case in the docs now:
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#opening-an-extension-page-in-a-new-tab

*Note: This example above is wrong as the callback function parameter is Object with the key reason and not reason directly.*

And another example here (this one is correct but does not open a tab):
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#example-uninstall-url

```js
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener((details) => {
  if (details.reason === chrome.runtime.OnInstalledReason.INSTALL) {
    // Code to be executed on first install
    // eg. open a tab with a url
    chrome.tabs.create({
      url: "https://google.com"
    });
  } else if (details.reason === chrome.runtime.OnInstalledReason.UPDATE) {
    // When extension is updated
  } else if (details.reason === chrome.runtime.OnInstalledReason.CHROME_UPDATE) {
    // When browser is updated
  } else if (details.reason === chrome.runtime.OnInstalledReason.SHARED_MODULE_UPDATE) {
    // When a shared module is updated
  }
});
```

This code can be added to a background service worker: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/migrating_to_service_workers/

Comment: Looks like the example was fixed since now parameter is an object with key `reason`: `chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(({reason}) => {...`

Answer (score 5):

It would be better to place a "version" number so you can know when an extension is updated or installed.

It has been answered here:
[Detect Chrome extension first run / update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399389/chrome-extension-first-run)

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is adding the snippet  below to your `background.js` file

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function (object) {
    chrome.tabs.create({url: `chrome-extension://${chrome.runtime.id}/options.html`}, function (tab) {
        console.log("options page opened");
    });
});
```