# Safari extension first time run and update

Tags: safari, safari-extension

The solution for [same task in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399389/chrome-extension-first-run) works pretty well with one exception. Seems like Safari doesn't clean up it's `localStorage` then extension is uninstalled, so any subsequent installs of the extension with the same version doesn't create `onInstall` "event". Is there any workaround for this in Safari.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `safari.extension.settings` instead of `localStorage`.