# Flutter for web - how use Chrome Api?

Tags: google-chrome, flutter-web, google-chrome-app

I am creating my first Flutter app for web. I need using [Chrome api](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/). For example I need to use it:

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener

   or

   chrome.tabs...
```

but unfortunately I did not find any information about it.

Is it possible?

Comment: You can find for about event-onInstalled here https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#event-onInstalled

Comment: Also similar question and answer regarding chrome API is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/40614389/8074416 maybe you find some help from there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the `chrome.*` APIs are JavaScript just like all the other web APIs, so you can use Dart's JS support.

That means using Dart's [`js`](https://pub.dev/documentation/js/latest/) library.

For example, you could bind a function something like this (untested, without any type annotation, just an example)

```dart
@JS('chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener')
external void addInstalledListener(Function callback);
```

Edit:
If you'd rather pull in a dependency than roll your own, you can use something like [`chrome.dart`](https://github.com/dart-gde/chrome.dart).

```dart
import 'package:chrome/chrome_app.dart' as chrome;

void main() {
  chrome.runtime.getPlatformInfo().then((Map m) {
    print(m.toString());
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `chrome_extension` package on pub.dev: https://pub.dev/packages/chrome_extension
This is a typed Dart binding to all `chrome.*` APIs.

All the APIs are available and are generated from the Chrome IDL files.

Example using `chrome.tabs.*` API

```dart
import 'package:chrome_extension/tabs.dart';

void main() async {
  var tab =
      await chrome.tabs.query(QueryInfo(active: true, currentWindow: true));
}
```

Example using `chrome.runtime.*` API

```dart
import 'package:chrome_extension/runtime.dart';

void main() async {
  chrome.runtime.onInstalled.listen((e) {
    print('OnInstalled: ${e.reason}');
  });
}
```